# Is ARCore supported on a Tango tablet?

Tags: android, google-project-tango, arcore

I have a Tango development kit from a couple years ago. Should I expect to be able to run ARCore apps on it?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google would have answered your question.... https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/

ARCore is designed to work on a wide variety of qualified Android phones running N and later. During the SDK preview, ARCore supports the following devices:

Google Pixel, Pixel XL, Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL
Samsung Galaxy S8 (SM-G950U, SM-G950N, SM-G950F, SM-G950FD, SM-G950W, SM-G950U1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did, however, Google for it. Specifically "ARCore supported devices" which finds [the page you linked to](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/#supported_devices) - which lists only Pixel and Samsung S8. So, "No Tango isn't supported" is the answer. However, this misses the point. Given Tango was the platform ARCore (or work that led to ARCore) was developed on, I had thought there might be a chance ARCore would work on it.